# re enable context menu HTML5

Tags: html, contextmenu

Hi I wanted to disabled the context menu on my site in general so I put `oncontextmenu= return false` in the body, but I want it enabled for one specific image on the site. Is there any way to re enable the context menu for this specific element?

Answer (score 0):

nYour mistake is to add it to the body tag, because this effectively ensures that an "oncontextmenu" event is added to *every* element that is a child of `<body>` - this is because of event "bubbling" in the DOM.

Here is an example that I think achieves what you're looking for:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1 oncontextmenu="test();">Right click me to do custom stuff!</h1>
    <h1>Right click me and the usual should happen</h1>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        window.alert("Custom stuff happens!");
    }
</script>
</html>
```

While it is possible to prevent propagation of events (see jQuery's https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/ function as a good way to do this), in your case the above should do the trick without needing a lot of extra code to decide whether the element clicked was supposed to respond to the event or not.

Comment: I do realize my approach might not be the best, but the question remains if I hypothetically wanted to "restore" the default context menu is that possible? (so basically something like =return true)

Comment: Yes, you could select the element using Javascript and remove the Event Listener.